# I get an error on trying to get the img.src from my Html textfield

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following is my function that is called on click of a button.

The goal is to get the text value entered by the user and use it as an image source and finally display the image on the html body.

```
function ButtonClick() {
        var link = document.createElement("a");

    // create an image element.
    var MyImg = document.createElement("img");

    var MyImg.src = document.getElementById("textfield").value;

    // append it to a list of elements.
    link.appendChild(MyImg);    

    // append the newly added image to the html page body.
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // clear textfield for next image src.
    document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";    
}
```

The error I receive is on line#7: `"var MyImg.src = document.getElementById("textfield").value;"`

SyntaxError: **missing ; before statement** example.js:19

*edited code after the fist suggestion.

Comment: `document.createElement("MyImg");` wrong syntax use `document.createElement("img");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyImg.src = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define variable once,

change

```
var MyImg = document.createElement("img");
var MyImg.src = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
```

to

```
var MyImg = document.createElement("img");
MyImg.src = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
```